# Apache Spark scala lowercase first letter using built-in function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to lowerCase the first letter of column values.

I can't find a way to lower only the first letter using built-in functions, I know there's `initCap` for capitalizing the data but I'm trying to decapitalize.
I tried using substring but looks a bit overkill and didn't work.

```
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("Spark"),("SparkHello"),("Spark Hello"))).toDF("name")
data.withColumn("name",lower(substring($"name",1,1)) + substring($"name",2,?))
```

I know I can create a custom UDF but I thought there's may be a built-in solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Spark SQL [`substring`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#substring) method, which allows neglecting the length argument (and will get the string until the end):

```
data.withColumn("name", concat(lower(substring($"name",1,1)), expr("substring(name,2)"))).show
+-----------+
|       name|
+-----------+
|      spark|
| sparkHello|
|spark Hello|
+-----------+
```

Note that you cannot `+` strings. You need to use `concat`.